# Where is scripted the Dalaran Well teleport (game object)?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, azerothcore

When you try to reach the Dalaran Well in Dalaran, you are teleported to the sewers.

It is using this Game object: `Doodad_Dalaran_Well_01` (id = `193904` )

Where is it scripted? How?

I've found nothing in the table `smart_scripts`, and found nothing in the core about this specific id so I'm curious because this type of teleport is really better than clicking on a game object

Answer (score 1):

This gameobject is a unique case because it works like instance teleports do. If you check the `gameobject_template` table, you will see that it has several `Data` columns that have diferent values based on the `type` of the gameobject.
The gameobject you are refering too is the Well It self but the portal gameobject inside the well gives the player a dummy spell to tell the core that the player has been teleported (spell ID 61652).
For the specific case of the dalaran well, it's type is 30 which means, as the [documentation](http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/gameobject_template) says, `GAMEOBJECT_TYPE_AURAGENERATOR`. As soon as the player is in range, a dummy aura is cast on him to notify the core that this areatrigger has been activated (You could do stuff when player gets hit by the dummy spell).

The trick here is a bunny, but not the bunny itself since it is there mostly to determine an areatrigger. If you use command .go gobject 61148 you can check him out, he's inside the well.

Areatriggers are a DBC object that are actually present on our database on `world.areatrigger`. You can check the columns [here](http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/DBC-AreaTrigger). When the player enters the Radius box specified on the areatrigger, another thing happens in the core which is `world.areatrigger_teleport`.

If you run the following query you will be able to check the position where the trigger will teleport the player to.

```
SELECT * FROM areatrigger_teleport WHERE `Name` LIKE '%Dalaran Well teleporter%';
```

Comment: Thank you, will use this next time I want to make a good teleporter.